# Use Google Cloud Run Environment variables in Vue 3

Tags: environment-variables, vuejs3, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

How can I access environment variables on Google Cloud Run at runtime in my Vue 3 project?

In my cloudbuild, I add environment variables with this line:

```
"--set-env-vars=TEST=tested"
```

I can see that the TEST environment variable was added to my revision.

However, in my Vue3 code, any attempt to retrieve the TEST environment variable returns undefined.

```
console.log(import.meta.env.TEST);
console.log(process.env.TEST);
```

Both lines return undefined.

Thanks

Comment: To expose the environment variables to the runtime environment, you need to add them to the "Environment Variables" section of your Cloud Run service.

Comment: Hi, I did that but the console.log code above return undefined in both cases. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your Vue.JS does not run on your Cloud Run environment, but in your browser. The Cloud Run service simply serve the static files that are ran in your browser.

Therefore, the environment is not Cloud Run, but your computer, and of course the variables are not there.

To solve that, you must replace the value before your code generation and packaging.

Comment: Hi guillaume, do you mean add the env vars to the Docker file (just use replacement values set in Google Cloud run)?

Comment: No, no, directly in your VueJS code! Env Var in Dockerfile is the same as Cloud Run. It's taken into account only when you run the code on the server, but this time the JS run on your browser!